# .net interpretation simple formula c#

Tags: c#

I would like to give a textbox to the user where a price may be set so something like this:

"[Quantity]*0.15+5"

which would result in a price of 6.50 for ten units (Quantity=10). Or another example:

"if(Date.month>10;[Quantity]*0.15+5;[Quantity]*0.15+0)"

which would give a different price from November to December than in the rest of the year.

These are just examples - what I want to achieve are large possibilities to set price rules depending an variables and including calculation.

I wonder how to achieve this in c#. Is there any way to interpret code that is written into a textbox during runtime?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] - where it is clear what `Date` is referring to, `Quantity` is referring to and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is an embeddable scripting engine. I would strongly suggest Jint. Its a very c# friendly javascript engine. You will feed it paramters (Quantity, Date, ... in your examples) and the text to execute, it will return the asnwer

https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

Comment: Hi @pm100 - thanks for this greate input - exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile so I can't give an example but, to do this without embedding a complete scripting engine, which might be overkill, just use event handlers.

Have a textbox for Quantity and a textbox for Price (maybe just a label). Implement an event handler for the Quantity textbox, focus lost maybe. In the handler, get the Quantity value, validate it (is an integer, etc), do the calculation and update the Price textbox/label with the value.

This can be extended easily to also look up the values in a Date textbox.

You can even get fancy and do this with a DataGridView bound to a BindingList of Price items so the Price is updated whenever any cell in a row is changed.

Comment: he has logic `if` ,... in his text. Thats tough to do

Comment: It wasn't clear to me he wanted that text entered by the user. An embedded scripting engine is great but if that's the extent of his needs, simple `Start Date` and `End Date` text boxes are an easy fix. Depending on his target audience, embedded scripting may be a bit much.

Comment: Hello @sraboy, thanks for the idea. This isn't what I am looking for because I do not want to change the interface but give a greate freedom to set price rules from very simple to very complexe. But thanks again for taking the time to respond !